# C# - Process.Start - using global variable as password - "cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Security.SecureString'

Tags: c#, security, global-variables, process.start, securestring

I designed a login form and wanted the username and password entered to be stored as variables I could call in other forms (overall program is a collection of .exe files and powershell scripts that I want to run as the username and password initially entered in my login form).

At the start of the program I created "global variables" using this code:

```
class usernameGlobalVariable
    {
        public static string var = "";
    }
    class passwordGlobalVariable
    {
        public static string var = "";
    }
```

In the login form I stored the username and password entered into these global variables this way:

```
private void usernameTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        usernameGlobalVariable.var = usernameTextBox.Text;
    }


    private void passwordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        passwordGlobalVariable.var = passwordTextBox.Text;
    }
```

When I want to start a process I call it using this code (to run it as the username and password stored by the login form):

```
string fileName = "c:\\hdatools\\Ping2.exe";
string arguments = "";
string domain = "vantage";
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    Process.Start(
    fileName,
    arguments,
    usernameGlobalVariable.var,
    passwordGlobalVariable.var,
    domain);

    }
```

The main error I get is on the line `passwordGlobalVariable.var,`
The error says

> Argument 4: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Security.SecureString'

I've tried different ways to try to convert `passwordGlobalVariable.var' to a secure string, or to give another string variable its contents and then render that variable as a secure string.  I've finally run out of ideas.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Why do you use a [reserved keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx) to name a variable? This is very confusing and misleading. An example to not follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Argument 4: cannot convert from 'string' to
>   'System.Security.SecureString'

because `var` is a `string` and not a `SecureString`, look:

```
class passwordGlobalVariable
{
   public static string var = "";
}
```

So change it to:

```
class passwordGlobalVariable
{
   public static SecureString var;
}
```

And later on, change your `passwordTextBox_TextChanged` event-handler to convert your password `string` into a `SecureString`:

```
private void passwordTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in passwordTextBox.Text.ToCharArray())
   {
     passWord.AppendChar(c);
   }

    passwordGlobalVariable.var = passWord;
}
```

A small **side-note**: Refrain from using the `var` word because one can be confused with the C#'s [`var` contextual keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383973.aspx).

Comment: @Yair Nevet thanks!  unfortunately it does not like my quotes.  It underlines my "" and the error says **Cannot implicitly convert type 'string to 'System.Security.SecureString'**

Comment: @Yair Nevet thanks again--I changed that and it underlines **passWord** on the line `passwordGlobalVariable.var = passWord;`

Error says **Argument 4: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Security.SecureString'

Comment: @superKing you should have no string fields in your data structures.

Comment: @YairNevet you are the man!  That certainly did the trick and I hope others can benefit from this answer.  I would vote it up if I had enough points.  For some reason someone voted down my question.  No idea why...anyway thanks again, bud! :D

Comment: @asadali it is not needed since var is a contextual keyword and not a completly reserved one.

Comment: @YairNevet Yep, I am aware of that, it was only to refresh my memory since I thought that `@` could only be used for classes, not variables.

Answer (score 2):

The code below create a SecureString from the string var:

```
   SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
   foreach (char c in var.ToCharArray())
                  passWord.AppendChar(c);
```

Comment: thanks (and sorry as i'm new to coding) but will this make a new variable called passWord?  Should I use the passWord variable to store the text in the password field?  Will this variable be available globally?  Thanks again

Comment: You can keep use the SecureString to store the passoword.

Answer (score 0):

```
var secureUsername = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in usernameGlobalVariable.var)
{
    secureUsername.AppendChar(c);
}

var securePassword = new SecureString();
foreach (char c in passwordGlobalVariable.var)
{
    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
}
```

This will give you two SecureStrings that you can pass into the Process.Start method

Comment: thank you--I tried this, but it underlines **var** saying _A namespace cannot directly contain members such as fields or methods_  It also underlines **SecureString** and says _Expected class, delegate, enum, interface, or struct_

Comment: `Process.Start` overloads accepts only one `SecureString` and it should be a password and not a username.